# How do I insert binary data into a DB using Laravel?

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel

I'm trying to insert binary data into a PostgreSQL database using Laravel 4 and its Eloquent ORM.  I have the following in a migration:

```
Schema::create('DataBlobs', function($table) {
    $table->increments('Id');
    $table->binary('Data');
});
```

After running the migration, I've verified that it creates a PostgreSQL BYTEA column.  Great!  So I put this in a database seeder function:

```
DB::table('DataBlobs')->delete();
// $d contains the binary data I want to insert into the database.
$d = base64_decode($raw_b64data);
$i = new DataBlob();
$i->Data = $d;
$i->save();
```

When I run that seeder, however, I get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[22021]: Character not in repertoire: 7 ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x89 (SQL: insert into "DataBlobs" ("Data") values (*binary gibberish that my console tries to render*)

I've validated using var_dump and bin2hex that $d is in fact a binary string that contains the data I want, but from the error, it looks like Laravel is trying to insert the binary data as a UTF8 string instead of as binary data. I've been googling for a day now, and I can't find any examples of how to insert binary data into a database using Laravel.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I've found that I can insert binary data using '\\xDEADBEEF' formatted hex strings, but if the string goes over 4678 characters (4680 including the \x prefix), it silently fails and the binary data doesn't get stored with the rest of the data. I'm at my wit's end here. Am I seriously going to have to fall back on issuing manual queries to PostgreSQL and bypassing Laravel's database features? :(

Comment: Hope the following resource will help you: [MySQL BLOB and PostgreSQL Bytea are not alternatives](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3669)

Answer (score -1):

You can use
DB::unprepared( $code );
or 
 DB::insert()