# invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x89 PostgreSQL Laravel 8

Tags: php, database, laravel, postgresql

*I am working in Laravel 8 on a windows 10 machine.* 

Full error:

```
SQLSTATE[22021]: Character not in repertoire: 7 ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x89
```

I want to insert a QR code into a PostgreSQL database. On my localhost this works fine with a MySQL database, however on my remote host, Heroku, I get this error:
`invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x89`

I have tried to change the encoding of the remote database in my `config\database.php` to match the same encoding of my local database, which is `utf8mb4` , but this did not work.

**Generate QR code and store it in database `database\seeders\DatabaseSeeder.php`**

```
use SimpleSoftwareIO\QrCode\Facades\QrCode;
use App\Models\QrCodeClient;

$client1qr = QrCode::format('png')->encoding('utf8')->size(100)->generate($client1->id);

        QrCodeClient::create([
            'client_id' => $client1->id,
            'qrcode' => $client1qr,
        ]);
```

*`QrCode::format('png')->encoding('utf8')->size(100)->generate($client1->id);` was at first just `QrCode::format('png')->size(100)->generate($client1->id);` but still gave the same error.* 
**Migration file for `QrCodeClient` Model**

```
Schema::create('qr_code_clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('client_id');
            $table->binary('qrcode');
            $table->index('client_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

**Configuration of pgsql**

```
'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'schema' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ],
```

I have looked at other questions regarding this topic but I didn't really find any useful information for my specific case. 
Can anybody tell me what I need to do to store a PNG file in a PostgreSQL database as a binary?
**Edit: Solution** 
I've changed

```
$client1qr = QrCode::format('png')->encoding('utf8')->size(100)->generate($client1->id);

QrCodeClient::create([
            'client_id' => $client1->id,
            'qrcode' => $client1qr,
        ]);
```

to

```
$client1qr = QrCode::format('png')->generate($client1->id);
$escaped1 = base64_encode($client1qr);

QrCodeClient::create([
           'client_id' => $client1->id,
           'qrcode' => $escaped1,
       ]);
```

Then to show it in the front end:

```
<?php
$my_bytea = stream_get_contents($bed->client()->first()->QrCode()->first()->qrcode);
$my_string = pg_unescape_bytea($my_bytea);
$html_data = htmlspecialchars($my_string);
?>
<td><img src="data:image/png;base64,{{$html_data}}"></td>
```

Comment: Show the code that does the insert, that's going to be what's generating the error.

Comment: @Sammitch `QrCodeClient::create(['client_id' => $client1->id, 'qrcode' => $client1qr,]);`

Comment: I suspect if you look at the table definition that the column is not binary. [This old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22270935/how-do-i-insert-binary-data-into-a-db-using-laravel) is the same. I'm not familiar with postgresql but in mysql the command would be `SHOW CREATE TABLE qr_code_clients` to view the column definitions.

Comment: There's also this [MySQL-specific workaround](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1606#issuecomment-650633301) to a similar problem. Not sure what the equivalent would be for PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$client1qr = QrCode::format('png')->encoding('utf8')->size(100)->generate($client1->id);

QrCodeClient::create([
            'client_id' => $client1->id,
            'qrcode' => $client1qr,
        ]);
```

to

```
$client1qr = QrCode::format('png')->generate($client1->id);
$escaped1 = base64_encode($client1qr);

QrCodeClient::create([
           'client_id' => $client1->id,
           'qrcode' => $escaped1,
       ]);
```

Then to show it in the front end:

```
<?php
$my_bytea = stream_get_contents($bed->client()->first()->QrCode()->first()->qrcode);
$my_string = pg_unescape_bytea($my_bytea);
$html_data = htmlspecialchars($my_string);
?>
<td><img src="data:image/png;base64,{{$html_data}}"></td>
```

Comment: If that QR code is binary data, why don't you store it as `bytea`?